# EditText highlighted when touched on widget in android 3.0?

Tags: android, widget

Has anyone ever successfully implemented an EditText in a widget?

Comment: What is your question? The one on the title or the one on the body? What is the problem you're facing? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If by "in a widget", you really mean "in an app widget", `EditText` is not supported in an app widget.